# Requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle

Tags: laravel, datatables, composer-php, serverside-datatable

I'm trying to install yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle using the command:

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- yajra/laravel-datatables[dev-master, v9.0.0] require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle 10.* -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle[v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].
- yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle 10.x-dev is an alias of yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
- yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle[dev-master, v10.0.0, ..., v10.1.2] require illuminate/database ^9 -> found illuminate/database[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- yajra/laravel-datatables 9.0.x-dev is an alias of yajra/laravel-datatables dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
- Root composer.json requires yajra/laravel-datatables ^9.0 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables[v9.0.0, 9.0.x-dev (alias of dev-master)].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

My laravel framework version is v8.83.22.

Bellow is my composer.json file showing all my dependencies and requirements

```
      {
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^1.0.0",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "intervention/image": "^2.6",
    "jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator": "^2.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.54",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.3",
    "laraveldaily/laravel-invoices": "3.0",
    "pragmarx/tracker": "^4.0",
    "rap2hpoutre/fast-excel": "^4.0",
    "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^4.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.6",
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
}
```

Note that the requirements are just the minimum such as php from which I have version 8.0.8 installed and laravel framework is v8.83.22

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravelv8.83.22

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a user mentioned, you need to use the previous version (9) because the latest one (10) is only supporting `Laravel 9.x+` and you are using `Laravel 8.x`.

```bash
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^9.0
```

I also saw you mentioned:

> Tried that and got the following error: [InvalidArgumentException]   Package yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle at version 9.0 has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version:       - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v9.0.0 requires php ^7.1.3 which does not match your installed version 8.0.8.

That means you are using `PHP 8.0` but `yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^9.0` only supports `7.1 <= PHP > 8.0`, so instead use this one:

```bash
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^9.21.2
```

That version's [`composer.json`](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/blob/v9.21.2/composer.json) is like this:

```json
"require": {
  "php": "^7.1.3|^8",
  "illuminate/database": "5.8.*|^6|^7|^8|^9",
  "illuminate/filesystem": "5.8.*|^6|^7|^8|^9",
  "illuminate/http": "5.8.*|^6|^7|^8|^9",
  "illuminate/support": "5.8.*|^6|^7|^8|^9",
  "illuminate/view": "5.8.*|^6|^7|^8|^9"
},
```

Meaning that it will allow you to use any Laravel >= 5.8.x but also allow you to use `PHP >= 7.1`.

---

Yajra version [9.0 `composer.json`](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/blob/v9.0.0/composer.json) did not support that before, that is why it is failing for you:

```json
"require": {
  "php": "^7.1.3",
  "illuminate/database": "5.8.*",
  "illuminate/filesystem": "5.8.*",
  "illuminate/http": "5.8.*",
  "illuminate/support": "5.8.*",
  "illuminate/view": "5.8.*"
},
```

You can see it only supported Laravel 5.8 and `7.1 <= PHP > 8.0`

Answer (score 3):

The most recent version of that particular package is `10.x` which is only supported by Laravel `9.x` and above.

The `composer require` you're using will pull in version `10.x` which isn't supported by your Laravel 8 installation, therefore provide composer with the specific version of the package that is supported for Laravel `8.x`:

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^9.0
```

You can check [version compatibility on the package GitHub page](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables#laravel-version-compatibility).

Comment: Tried that and got the following error ```[InvalidArgumentException]
  Package yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle at version 9.0 has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version:  
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v9.0.0 requires php ^7.1.3 which does not match your installed version 8.0.8.```

Comment: @TheOnlySmartBoy Can you add your `composer.json` file to your original question?

Comment: @TheOnlySmartBoy I think you need to investigate your `PHP` installation. I used your `composer.json` file with `PHP 8.0.21` on Ubuntu 22.04 and got the `laravel-datatables-oracle` package installed successfully.